# MySQL GROUP BY how to get data from first element

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have next table with data:
[image]

And I run this query:

```
select *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `timeu`, AVG(`value`) AS `valuea`
from `values` 
group by `currency`, DATE(`time` - interval 7 day) 
order by `id` asc
```

In result I get

[image]

As you can see `id`s are: `1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12`. I want to have `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` - how can I simply build my query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not do a `group by`.

I suspect you can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
select v.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `timeu`,
      (SELECT AVG(`value`)
       from values v2
       where v2.currency = v.currency and
             v2.time >= v2.time - interval 7 day
      ) as `valuea`
from `values` v
order by `id` asc ;
```